# Symfony routes keywords

Tags: php, symfony

I am very confused about Symfony routes.

I have this file, below, and I can't understand the different keywords. For example I don't know how "prefix" works or "pattern" works

```
fos_user_security:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
prefix: /profile

#HWIOAuthBundle routes
hwi_oauth_security:
resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_connect:
resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_redirect:
resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
prefix:   /login

facebook_login:
pattern: /login/check-facebook

google_login:
pattern: /login/check-google

stefano_zulli:
resource: "@StefanoZulliBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```

Comment: Read the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

The pattern (or path) is the url path that will be appended to your root domain (see [this part of the  routing docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#basic-route-configuration)).

The prefix will be the pattern that is added to all routes contained in the "resource" (see [this part of the  routing docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#prefixing-imported-routes)).

For example..

```
fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

Is loading the resource `@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml` with the prefix `/profile` meaning that the contained routes would prefixed with that "prefix"

For example `@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml` there is the following route..

```
fos_user_profile_edit:
    pattern: /edit
    defaults:
        _controller: FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit
```

but with the prefix `/profile` it's full path (providing there are no other prefixes in parent routing files) would be at `/profile/edit` rather than just `/edit`.